# ajax call code behind method not working

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have a function in jquery like

```
$(".menuspan").click(function(){ bindResult(); });

function bindResult()
{
$.get("settings.aspx/TestMethod");
}
```

and in code behind i have

```
[WebMethod(Description = "bind")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public void  TestMethod()
{

}
```

But its not calling the TestMethod, However if i put this method in asmx, and give the asmx path, its working perfectly, what's i am doing wrong

**I cannot use PageMethod, as i can't declare the method as static**

Any help Please

Thanks

Comment: You need to wrap url in quotes `$.get("settings.aspx/TestMethod");`

Comment: its in quotes already, typing mistake.. Sorry

Comment: where do you call this method. Could you show us?

Comment: i am calling bindResult method on a span click, and that call is working fine i have checked with alert method